# Vertical sliding menu

Tags: jquery

I have created a menu. It's pretty basic but I got a problem which i haven't figured out so far.

When page loads. All links are hidden in menu tab. When user clicks the tab links show up . But when user clicks any link tab collapsed again. So every time user has to click the tab to click any link.

I want the links to be shown untill the user clicks the tab.

Please check my code below. Please help, it's been two days now i am dealing with this.

```
<a id="doc_test" >
    <img src="../../images/menu_icons/documents_button.png" border="0"  />
</a>
<br />
<div id="docSubLink_test" style="padding-left:10px;display: none;">
    <a class=""  id="d1" href="#" >apple</a><br />
    <a class=""   id="d2" href="#" >grapes</a><br />
    <a class=""   id="d3" href="#" >orange</a><br />
    <a class=""   id="d4" href="#" >peach</a><br />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if($('#docSubLink_test').is(':visible')) {
   $('#doc_test').click(function(){
       alert('1');
       //$('docSubLink_test').css("display","inline");  
       $('#docSubLink_test').slideUp(500);
       //$('docSubLink_test').slideUp('medium'); 
   });
}

if($('#docSubLink_test').is(':hidden')) {
   $('#doc_test').click(function(){
       //alert('1');
       //$('docSubLink_test').css("display","inline");  
       $('#docSubLink_test').show(500);
       //$('docSubLink_test').slideUp('medium'); 
   });
}

//Link to other page
$('#d1').click(function(){  
    $.get('http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?orange',function(data){         
        $('body').html(data); 
    }); 
});
$('#d2').click(function(){          
    $.get('http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?apple',function(data){
        $('body').html(data); 
    }); 
});
$('#d3').click(function(){  
    $.get('http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?peach',function(data){
        $('body').html(data); 
    });
});
$('#d4').click(function(){  
    $.get('http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?grapes',function(data){
        $('body').html(data); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You are replacing the whole body with the ajax results... so the menu and everything else is overwritten.. you need to only update the parts you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already fixed that one. As I was refreshing the body with ajax result. so everytime i was clicking any link it refreshes the whole body containing menu itself. so menu collapses.
Right answer was given by Gaby aka G. Petrioli in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#doc_test').click(function () {
                $('#docSubLink_test').is(':visible') ? $('#docSubLink_test').slideUp(500) : $('#docSubLink_test').slideDown(500);
            });

            $('.subLinkD').click(function () {
                var obj = $(this);

                $('#docSubLink_test').slideUp(500);

                //                $('#loadHerfContent').load(obj.data('href'), function (response, status, xhr) {
                //                    if (status == "error") {
                //                        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                //                        $("#loadHerfContent").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                //                    }
                //                });

                $.get(obj.data('href'), function (data) {
                    $('#loadHerfContent').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="doc_test" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: large; font-weight: bolder;">
        <img src="../../images/menu_icons/documents_button.png" border="0" />Main Tab
    </a>
    <br />
    <div id="docSubLink_test" style="padding-left: 10px; display: none;">
        <a class="subLinkD" id="d1" href="#" data-href="http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?apple">
            apple</a><br />
        <a class="subLinkD" id="d2" href="#" data-href="http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?grapes">
            grapes</a><br />
        <a class="subLinkD" id="d3" href="#" data-href="http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?orange">
            orange</a><br />
        <a class="subLinkD" id="d4" href="#" data-href="http://www.abc.com/products/doc_test.php?peach">
            peach</a><br />
    </div>
    <div id="loadHerfContent">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bro you are doing the same thing, which I was doing. After clicking the sub links, menu closes again.